# get value from splistitem

Tags: sharepoint-server, splistitem

I'm face to a strange issue.
I get an splistitem with a caml query
->that's ok and validated with caml query builder.

After that, i'm try to get the title or any other meta of the item.

Here is how i have the splistitem

```
SPListItem item = null;
        try
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + _searchedField + "'/><Value Type='Text'>" + _searchedValue + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            query.RowLimit = 1;
            foreach (string s in _viewField)
            {
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='"+s+"' />";
            }
            SPList list = _web.Lists[_listLookup];
            item = list.GetItems(query).Cast<SPListItem>().First();

            //item = list.GetItemById(item.ID);
            //SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
            //if (items.Count > 0)
            //    item = items[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //diagnosticsService.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("BU Finance", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, "generateTree = " + ex.Message + "--" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return item;
```

And then i try to get the value and always i get back {Title} or the name of meta

```
_item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");
item.Fields["Title"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the field, not it's value.

To get the value use this:

```
item["Title"]
```